# What file is /dev/btrfs-control?

Tags: debian, centos, devices

I can't find any explanation about this file in the official documentation, I just know from the official documentation in devices.txt that this file is:
"234 = /dev/btrfs-control Btrfs control device".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in [`fs/btrfs/super.c` in kernel source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/fs/btrfs/super.c?h=v6.7.3#n2346), and used for various BtrFS-specific `ioctl()` system calls.

Generally, unless you are developing the `libbtrfs` library of the `btrfs-progs` package, you don't need to care about it.

But if you are curious, see[`Documentation/btrfs-ioctl.rst` in btrfs-progs package](https://github.com/kdave/btrfs-progs/blob/master/Documentation/btrfs-ioctl.rst), read the detailed description of each BtrFS ioctl, and see which ones have the `ioctl fd` specified as "file descriptor of the control device".

Alternatively, you can look at the [`btrfs_control_ioctl` function in the kernel source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/fs/btrfs/super.c?h=v6.7.3#n2136), which implements the ioctls accessible through the control device. At the time of this writing, there are four of them:

- `BTRFS_IOC_SCAN_DEV`
- `BTRFS_IOC_FORGET_DEV`
- `BTRFS_IOC_DEVICES_READY`
- `BTRFS_IOC_GET_SUPPORTED_FEATURES`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I originally tried to find the answer in the source code as well, but unfortunately I was not sure about the structure of the source code and could not find anything about it, so I was curious how did you find it in the source code?

Comment: `grep -r btrfs-control linux-6.6.15/fs/btrfs/*` (note: searching without the `/dev/`prefix), plus a bit of prior knowledge about how registering a device in Linux kernel generally works. Basically, I expected to find a `struct miscdevice` tying the name of the device and the `fops` structure (type name `struct file_operations`) for it together, then that structure would contain a pointer to the function that identifies the relevant ioctls (`btrfs_control_ioctl`) and calls further functions to implement them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.